# npm refuses to install mongoose

Tags: mongoose, npm-install

```
  ~ npm install mongoose
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install mongoose as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com
```

this has been asked before, however the answer does not work when using npm to uninstall mongoose  the following occurs:

```
 ~ npm uninstall mongoose
npm WARN karma-chai@0.1.0 requires a peer of chai@* but none was installed.
```

so uninstall is failing to happen

Comment: do you have a package.json? what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a try in this way,adding `"mongoose":"*"` in 'package.json' file then code in cmd

```
~npm insatll
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know now if it needs the answer or not because this question is almost 5 years old but the problem is you are trying to install mongoose inside the same dependency change the name of your dependency

```
{
  "name": "mongoose",
  ...
}
```

to something like this

```
{
  "name": "mongoose_playground",
  ...
}
```